# Java Thread join with two threads and a static variable

Tags: java, multithreading, static

```
public class TestThread2 {

    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                for (int i=1; i<=100000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }           
            }
        });
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                for (int i=1; i<=100000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }           
            }
        });
        t.start();
        t1.start();

        try{
            t.join();
            t1.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

The above code prints various values of count such as 131938, 127518 etc. But I think it should always print 20000 as after join() is called, main thread cannot move to next statement until current thread dies. I know I'm missing a basic concept here, but I'm not able to figure it out so please help.

Comment: `i++` isn't atomic. This is Java concurrency 101; go and read Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: Typically you'd call `await()` on a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which starts at 2 and is `countDown()` when each thread finished (finally block)

Comment: Not related that much but to get the same answer always you can set affinity and only use one core. Then you will always get the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` isn't atomic. It's effectively:

```
int j = i;
i = j + 1;
```

If two threads are trying to do this at the same time, the reads and writes from different threads could interleave, meaning that the value isn't strictly incrementing in each thread.

Additionally, there is no guarantee that the increased value from one thread is visible to the other thread.

Instead of using `int`, use `AtomicInteger`, and `addAndGet`. `AtomicInteger` guarantees both the atomicity of the incrementation and the visibility of the value between threads.

```
static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

// In the thread:
count.incrementAndGet();
```

---

Note that something very similar to your example is described in [the Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are not synchronizing the variables. Instead of `static int count`, use an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes main thread blocks on `join()`. But the main thread does not write to the variable `count`, so it does not matter what main thread is doing. You have 2 threads, `t` and `t1`, which read and write the same variable `count` without any synchronization, and indeed it causes unstable results.